# Why are these type inferences happening in GraphDB?

Tags: rdf, rdfs, graphdb, turtle-rdf

I've the following .ttl File:

```
@Prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>.
@Prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>.
@Prefix ex: <http://www.example.com#>

ex:requires rdfs:domain ex:Function.
ex:requires rdfs:range ex:Information.
ex:provides rdfs:domain ex:Function.
ex:provides rdfs:range ex:Function.
ex:requires rdfs:domain ex:Display.
ex:DisplaysTo rdfs:domain ex:Display.
ex:DisplaysTo rdfs:range ex:User.

ex:F1 ex:requires ex:I1.
ex:F1 ex:provides ex:I2.
ex:D1 ex:requires ex:I2.
ex:D1 ex:DisplaysTo ex:U1.
```

which results in the following inferences once imported into GraphDB using the RDFS (Optimized) ruleset.

I1 and I2 are Type Information

U1 is Type User

D1 is Type Display and Type Function

F1 is Type Display and Type Function

The first 2 inferences I wanted, however for the last two inferences I want D1 to be only of Type Display, and F1 to be only of Type Function.

How do I change my .ttl file for this to be the case?

EDIT: Newer .ttl file with owl

```
@prefix : <http://www.semanticweb.org/alexbett/ontologies/2021/3/untitled-ontology-5#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@base <http://www.semanticweb.org/alexbett/ontologies/2021/3/untitled-ontology-5> .

:DisplaysTo rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
            rdfs:domain :Display ;
            rdfs:range :User .

:Provides rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
          rdfs:domain :Function ;
          rdfs:range :Information .

:Requires rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
          rdfs:domain :Display ,
                      :Function ;
          rdfs:range :Information .

:Display rdf:type owl:Class ;
         rdfs:subClassOf [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                           owl:onProperty :DisplaysTo ;
                           owl:minQualifiedCardinality "1"^^xsd:nonNegativeInteger ;
                           owl:onClass :User
                         ] ,
                         [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                           owl:onProperty :Requires ;
                           owl:minQualifiedCardinality "1"^^xsd:nonNegativeInteger ;
                           owl:onClass :Information
                         ] .

:Function rdf:type owl:Class ;
          rdfs:subClassOf [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                            owl:onProperty :Provides ;
                            owl:minQualifiedCardinality "1"^^xsd:nonNegativeInteger ;
                            owl:onClass :Information
                          ] ,
                          [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                            owl:onProperty :Requires ;
                            owl:minQualifiedCardinality "1"^^xsd:nonNegativeInteger ;
                            owl:onClass :Information
                          ] .

:Information rdf:type owl:Class .
:User rdf:type owl:Class .

:D1 rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ;
    :DisplaysTo :U1 ;
    :Requires :I2 .

:F1 rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ;
    :Provides :I2 ;
    :Requires :I1 .

:I1 rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual .
:I2 rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual .
:U1 rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual .
```

EDIT 2:
Instead of as above it should be:

```
:Display rdf:type owl:Class ;
         owl:intersectionOf [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                              owl:onProperty :DisplaysTo ;
                              owl:onClass :User
                            ] ,
                            [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                              owl:onProperty :Requires ;
                              owl:onClass :Information
                            ] .
```

Comment: impossible with RDF in your current form. I'm also not sure why you're wondering that this happens? I mean, you're saying *"everything that uses the ex:requires property is a ex:Function"* with `ex:requires rdfs:domain ex:Function.` and with `ex:requires rdfs:domain ex:Display.` you're additionally saying that *"everything that uses the ex:requires property is a ex:Display"* - so in the end, both things are statements supposed to be true, i.e. they hold. So it holds that *"everything that uses the ex:requires property is a ex:Display and a ex:Function"*

Comment: clearly, what you need are two different property for the "requires" relation if they are used in different domains. You could have a property `ex:requires` and then two subproperties `ex:requiresD` and `ex:requiresF` with each having a different domain

Comment: @UninformedUser Is there a way using RDFS to say that an object must have all relationships defined in rdfs for it to become an instance of that class. for example an object O1 must have both the relationships of Requires and DisplaysTo to be an instance of Display, not just one of the two?

Comment: not in RDFS, for this you need OWL which builds on top of RDF(S)

Comment: @UninformedUser I've tried using owl cardinality rules to specify that a Display must DisplayTo a minumum of 1 User. Yet it still assigns the function F1 as in instance of class Display despite that it has no property DisplaysTo. Is cardinality the correct way to do thsi using owl?

Comment: without showing what exactly you did now, impossible to give feedback. So which data and which reasoning profile?

Comment: @UninformedUser added latest .ttl file, does that provide what you need?

Comment: ok, thank's for the update  - but what is the question now or what is different from your initial example? The problem remains the same, exactly what I wrote in my first comment. The domain of the property `:Requires` is both ` :Display` and
                      `:Function` - so, of course `:F1` is an instance of `:Display`. Mutliple domains denote the intersection ("and") of those classes, not the union ("or")

Comment: @UninformedUser Okay so how would I write it such that it infers an object :F1 is of class :Function if it has both properties :Requires AND :Provides with it as the domain. And that an object :D1 is of Class :DIsplay if it has both properties :Requires AND :DisplaysTo with it as the domain. Such that it does not infer that :F1 is of class :Display and also does not infer that :D1 is of class :Function.

Comment: remove the domain axioms first, otherwise both will always belong to both types. Then just use the axioms you already have. But I'd go rather with `owl:someValuesFrom` if you you always have min cardinality of 1. And the direction of the subclass axiom is wrong. Currently, you're just saying "every function has ...", but you want to say "everything that has ... is a function" - so, switch subclass and superclass expressions

Comment: and indeed, as you're using OWL constructs, this is **not** part of RDFS reasoning for sure. you have to use something like `OWL-Horst` here

Comment: @UninformedUser Thanks, i removed the domain axioms and that cleared up the class errors. I do want to say "everything that has... is a function" but I'm not sure what you mean by switching the subclass and superclass expressions, could you provide an example?

Comment: just put what is "left" to the "right" and vice versa. I mean, instead of `:A rdfs:subClassOf :B`, do `:B rdfs:subClassOf :A` - in your case, as you want to have the intersection of both as you have `:C rdfs:subClassOf :A, :B .`, you have to use an `owl:intersectionOf`, i.e. `[a owl:Class ; owl:intersectionOf (:A :B)] rdfs:subClassOf :C .`

Comment: @UninformedUser so instead of the previous method i had, it should be as I've added in the question edit 2?

Comment: you have to change the subclass axiom as I've shown in my previous comment.